# How to extend or override BeginForm to include a AntiForgeryToken field

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3, dry, csrf

I was reading this article (http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx) about how to prevent CSRF attacks.  It seems like the solution is to create a tag inside each form.

```
<%: this.Html.AntiForgeryToken(Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt)%>
```

However, I really don't want to copy and paste that code inside of each form.  I would like to extend or override the BeginForm to create a BeginSecureForm that automatically adds the AntiForgeryToken.  I am not sure how to add content inbetween of the BeginForm and EndForm.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 to everyone for helping me solve an vaguely related issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use this instead, to place the token at the right place, after the form :

```
public static MvcForm BeginAntiForgeryForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var mvcForm = htmlHelper.BeginForm();
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(htmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken().ToHtmlString());
        return mvcForm;
    }
```