# Automating Anti Forgery Token Validation on MVC Apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Is there a way to automatically have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` annotation on all HTTP post methods on a controller without having to explicitly defining it?

and also is there a way to extend the `MVC Html.BeginForm()` helper to include the anti forgery token at all times?

and finally the purpose of doing this is to keep things consistent across the application, can there be a reason not to do this for some scenarios?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Chameleon Forms](https://github.com/MRCollective/ChameleonForms)?

Comment: @Bringer128 thanks for that, but not inclined to use a framework for achieving this one thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend or override BeginForm to include a AntiForgeryToken field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552830/how-to-extend-or-override-beginform-to-include-a-antiforgerytoken-field)

Comment: @V-SHY the answer in the question above addresses part of the problem.

Comment: Check out https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/adding-asp-net-mvc-anti-forgery-tokens-to-all-post-requests-easily/

Comment: How to add `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` to all actions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213345/how-can-i-set-the-validateantiforgerytoken-globally

How to include AntiForgeryToken to all forms.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552830/how-to-extend-or-override-beginform-to-include-a-antiforgerytoken-field

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was researching this topic myself and compiled full solution below and also [here](https://gist.github.com/vadim-kovalyov/680c279c93b54d97ebb9). It consists of few parts including `AntiForgeryTokenFilterProvider` and `BeginSecureForm` helper method. It also allows to skip validation for a single action with `DisableAntiForgeryCheckAttribute`.

```
public class AntiForgeryTokenFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        IEnumerable<FilterAttribute> filters = actionDescriptor.GetFilterAttributes(true);

        bool disableAntiForgery = filters.Any(f => f is DisableAntiForgeryCheckAttribute);

        string method = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

        if (!disableAntiForgery
            && String.Equals(method, "POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            yield return new Filter(new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute(), FilterScope.Global, null);
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class DisableAntiForgeryCheckAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
}

// Usage:
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //**//
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new AntiForgeryTokenFilterProvider());
        //**//
    }
}

// Html Helper method
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcForm BeginSecureForm(this HtmlHelper html, string action, string controller)
    {
        var form = html.BeginForm(action, controller);
        html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(html.AntiForgeryToken().ToHtmlString());

        return form;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent summary, wish this was voted higher. Bits and pieces are scattered around the web, but this puts it all together.